# Finding all terms near a given phrase

Tags: r

Is there a way to find all words that are associated with a given phrase?

For example, say I want to find all of the words next to the word "illness" in a string. The string has the word "illness" quite a bit, and I want to find all of the terms surrounding it, such as "has illness," "does not have illness," "might have illness," etc...

Comment: You'll need to come up with an NLP method for the distance if you want to do something like this. If you just want to contain the exact spelling illness, try `grepl("illness", variable_name)`

Comment: If you are interested in any phrasing, you could do something like extract every sentence that has the word "illness" in. If you are interested in finding out which words/phrases commonly precede "illness" you could instead look at extracting preceding word/2 words/3 words...n words and then looking at what the most frequent word combos are. Depends on whether this is just to get a sense / if it's one off.

Comment: PS, if you give an example chunk of text that would help as well :)

Comment: Is this in a database or a large string?

Comment: This is in a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have a vector of strings (isolated or as a column in a `data.frame`), then perhaps:

```r
s <- c("hello world illness quux bar not action illness",
       "not an illness", "no positive", "illness", "illness goodbye")
ret <- lapply(list(gregexpr("(\\S+)(?= illness)", s, perl = TRUE),
                   gregexpr("(?<=illness )(\\S+)", s, perl = TRUE)),
              regmatches, x = s)
Map(c, ret[[1]], ret[[2]])
# [[1]]
# [1] "world"  "action" "quux"  
# [[2]]
# [1] "an"
# [[3]]
# character(0)
# [[4]]
# character(0)
# [[5]]
# [1] "goodbye"
```

Each `gregexpr` finds a word (well, contiguous non-whitespace) followed by the literal `" illness"` or preceded by the literal `"illness "`. Because it returns a `list` with enough information to extract the substrings from the original, we use `regmatches(x=s, ...)` to extract the components.

(The `Map` command deals with the fact that the `lapply` result is a list, length 2, one for each regex. It merely concatenates the substrings from the first regex with the substrings from the second regex, "zipping" the matches for each string within the vector. If you look at `ret[[1]]` and/or `ret` as a whole, the benefit of this might make more sense.)

If you don't care in *which* string in the vector/column the surrounding words are found, then you can simply unlist this:

```r
unlist(ret)
# [1] "world"   "action"  "an"      "quux"    "goodbye"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite unclear what pattern exactly you want to match. So here's some options, using `str_extract`from the `stringr`package and positive lookahead:

```
dt <- c("I mean he's got to have some illness I suppose that",
        "whether you've had a serious illness or [unclear]",
        "No not what illnesses, terminal illness.",
        "Oh, Terminal illness, oh, sorry.",
        "Illness benefit on a joint life, last survivor plan?")

str_extract(dt, ".*(?=.(i|I)llness)") # any string prior to "illness"
[1] "I mean it's got to be some some" "whether you've had a serious"    "No not what illnesses, terminal"
[4] "Oh, Terminal"                    NA 

str_extract(dt, "(some|serious|terminal)(?=.(i|I)llness)") # specific words prior to "illness"
[1] "some"     "serious"  "terminal" NA         NA  

str_extract(dt, "\\w+\\b(?=.(i|I)llness)") # last word prior to "illness"
[1] "some"     "serious"  "what"     "Terminal" NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `kwic` function from quanteda. You can specify the number of words surrounding the term you are looking for. In the example I'm using 3, but that can be anything. The advantage is that you can store the outcome in a data.frame and then do some more investigations.

Using the example from @Chris Ruehlemann:

```
library(quanteda)

dt <- c("I mean he's got to have some illness I suppose that",
        "whether you've had a serious illness or [unclear]",
        "No not what illnesses, terminal illness.",
        "Oh, Terminal illness, oh, sorry.",
        "Illness benefit on a joint life, last survivor plan?")


out <- kwic(dt, pattern = "illness", window = 3,  valuetype = "regex")

out
 [text1, 8]        to have some |  illness  | I suppose that    
 [text2, 6]       had a serious |  illness  | or[ unclear       
 [text3, 4]         No not what | illnesses | , terminal illness
 [text3, 7] illnesses, terminal |  illness  | .                 
 [text4, 4]        Oh, Terminal |  illness  | , oh,             
 [text5, 1]                     |  Illness  | benefit on a  


data.frame(out)
  docname from to                  pre   keyword               post pattern
1   text1    8  8         to have some   illness     I suppose that illness
2   text2    6  6        had a serious   illness       or [ unclear illness
3   text3    4  4          No not what illnesses , terminal illness illness
4   text3    7  7 illnesses , terminal   illness                  . illness
5   text4    4  4        Oh , Terminal   illness             , oh , illness
6   text5    1  1                        Illness       benefit on a illness
```